# Open ethernet android fragment in your application

Tags: android, android-fragments, ethernet, application-settings

Is it possible to make your own GUI in your application and open Ethernet settings fragment without all menus on the left from Android, so that a user can only see Ethernet settings and cannot change anything else? Like loading Android fragment in your application fragment container?

Is there any way to also open other settings like WIF?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Ethernet ? Do you mean Wi-Fi connection ?

Comment: There is also ethernet setitngs in More -> Ethernet in Android 4.2. So you have both, ethernet and Wifi settings seperated